# How to create a new array by filtering only the necessary data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object which contains questions with different types `multiple`, `single` and `text`.

```
const data = {
    questions: [
        {
            "question": "Question 1",
            "value": [
                "value_1.1.1",
                "value_1.1.2"
            ],
            "type": "multiple",
            "options": [
                {
                    "value": "value_1.1.1",
                    "label": "Value 1.1.1"
                },
                {
                    "textValue":"Additional text value",
                    "value": "value_1.1.2",
                    "label": "Value 1.1.2"
                },
                {
                    "value":"value_1.1.3",
                    "label":"Value 1.1.3",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "question": "Question 2",
            "value": "value_2.1.1",
            "type": "single",
            "options": [
                {
                    "value": "value_2.1.1",
                    "label": "Value 2.1.1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "value_2.1.2",
                    "label": "Value 2.1.2"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "question":"Question 3",
            "textValue":"Test 12345",
            "type":"text"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a new array with objects, which contains the question key and the value key.

The value key must contain the label of the selected options.
For a multiple type, the value can contain multiple labels.
The selected option can be retrieved from the parent value key, if it is equal to the value of the option, I want to use the label of this option as value.

In some cases an option also contains a textValue (see 1.1.3), then this must also be added to the value.

So the new array should look like this for the example above:

```
const newData = [
    {
        question: "Question 1",
        value: ['Value 1.1.1', 'Value 1.1.2', 'Additional text value']
    },
    {
        question: "Question 2",
        value: ['Value 2.1.1']
    },
    {
        question: "Question 3",
        value: ['Test 12345']
    }
];
```

Comment: Where is `'Additional text value'` in the output coming from?

Comment: @adiga I missed to add that in selected option, updated the example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically loop over the questions, handling each by its own type. The tricky part is the `type: multiple` but it is managable.

Update: Fixed according to comment

```js
const data = {questions:[{question:"Question 1",value:["value_1.1.1","value_1.1.2"],type:"multiple",options:[{value:"value_1.1.1",label:"Value 1.1.1"},{value:"value_1.1.2",label:"Value 1.1.2"},{textValue:"test12",value:"value_1.1.3",label:"Value 1.1.3"}]},{question:"Question 2",value:"value_2.1.1",type:"single",options:[{value:"value_2.1.1",label:"Value 2.1.1"},{value:"value_2.1.2",label:"Value 2.1.2"},]},{question:"Question 3",textValue:"Test 12345",type:"text"}]};

function get_option_label(options, value) {
  return options.find(item => item.value == value).label || value
}

const newData = [];
data.questions.forEach(function(obj) {
  var new_obj = {
    question: obj.question
  }
  if (obj.type == "multiple") {
    new_obj.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.value))
    new_obj.value = new_obj.value.map(item => get_option_label(obj.options, item))

    // add textValue for multiple question
    // but only if its value is on parent
    var objText = obj.options.find((item) => item.textValue);
    if (objText && obj.value.indexOf(objText.value) >= 0) {
      new_obj.value.push(objText.textValue)
    }
  }
  if (obj.type == "single") {
    new_obj.value = [get_option_label(obj.options, obj.value)]
  }
  if (obj.type == "text") {
    new_obj.value = [obj.textValue]
  }
  newData.push(new_obj)

})

// now replacing all values with labels
console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0
}
```

Comment: Close to the answer, but not at all.

For example, if the value of a question is `value:["value_1.1.1","value_1.1.2"]` then the labels of 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 should be added to the new array instead of the value.

textValue for multipleChoice only needs to be added if the value of this option is also in the parent value. In this case `1.1.3` is not in the parent value so the `textValue` does not belong in the array.

But if `1.1.3` is in the parent value, then the textValue and label from this option must be added in the new array under value.

Comment: I first wanted to know if the general direction was correct. Fixed.